# Carry on index after cutting a list

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list:

```
l1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```

With the indexes and values:

```
ind  val
 0    2
 1    3
 2    5
 3    7
 4    11
 5    13
```

Now I slice the array with:

```
l2 = l1[3:]
```

And get:

```
ind  val
 0    7
 1    11
 2    13
```

But I want the indexes to remain the same as they were before the cutting:

```
ind  val
 3    7
 4    11
 5    13
```

Comment: From where is the `ind` column coming?

Comment: Looks like you want to use some other data structure, e.g. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe.

Comment: How does a list turn into that two column dataframe?

Comment: You could use `list(enumerate(l1))` to get a list of 2-tuples (index, value)... That'd retain the index value after slicing.

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas and series:

```py
import pandas as pd

list=[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

x = pd.Series(list) 

# Display sub serie
x.iloc[3:]

# Display sub serie values as a list
x.iloc[3:].tolist()

# Display sub serie index as a list
x.iloc[3:].index.tolist()
```